# Automating the creation of new file in windows folder

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I am trying to write a batch script which will check if there are any file with , say for example, .dll extension and if file exits then it should create new file with same name but with .txt extension.

so say I have test_12345.dll file present in folder then my script should see if this exits and create an empty file as test_12345.txt ( basically exact same name with .dll file but with different extension)

Can some expert help me to create this with batch script.

Regards
Sushant

Comment: `exists != exits` ;-) Good luck.

Comment: `bash` and `batch` are two different things.

Answer (score 0):

This is the `bash` script. :) You could try this in bash environment.

```
#!/bin/bash
dirname=$1
ext=$2
[ $# -eq 0 ] && { echo "Usage: $0 <path> <ext>" ex: $0 /tmp/ dll ; exit 1; }
find $dirname -type f -name "*.${ext}" | while read fname
do
name=$(dirname $fname)/$(basename $fname .${ext})
txtFile=$name.txt
if [ ! -e "$txtFile" ] ; then
    touch "$txtFile"
fi
done
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a windows bat script doing what you need.
Scans all DLLs in the current directory, then changes extension to `.txt` and creates an (almost) empty file. Full batch native, no external tools used.

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

for %%b in (*.dll) do (
set v=%%b
set u=!v:.dll=.txt!
echo. >!u!
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Supposing you are looking fo a [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file) solution, this is what you want:

```
for %%F in ("\path\to\folder\*.dll") do (
    > "%%~dpnF.txt" break
)
```

The `for` loop enumerates all `.dll` files in the given location `\path\to\folder\` (remove that part if you want to process the current working directory). `%%~dpnF` expands to drive, path and base name (without extension `.dll`) of the currently iterated item. The `break` command does nothing in modern Windows systems (it is just there for backwards compatibility with MS-DOS) and produces no output, hence I use it to create empty `.txt` files. `echo.` returns a line-break (so the files are not empty); furthermore the `.` syntax might even cause unexpected behaviour under some circumstances (the syntax `echo(` looks odd but it is secure).